# Choosing batman-adv interface based on port

Tags: policy-routing

I am working on a set up where I have bat0 and bat1 batman -adv networks. When non-mesh clients send packets on a certain port number, I want the connected node to be able to choose bat1 instead of bat0 for those packets. I managed to make this work by using ip rule and ip route and without bridging bat0 and bat1 to ethernet but I want something like this to work with all possible non-mesh clients connected to the network with a switch so I won't be able to know about their subnets.